# I have question about a proof in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I have a question about this proof:

> Let $X$ be a random variable and $n>0$. Then we have that $P(|X|\geq
> n) \leq \frac{E|X|}{n}$
>
> Proof: Let $Y: \begin{pmatrix} 0 & n\\ P(|X|<n) & P(|X| \geq n)
> \end{pmatrix}$ be a random variable. Then we have that $0 \leq Y \leq
> |X|$ e.g. $P(|X|-Y \geq 0) = 1$ and $E(|X|-Y) \geq 0$ so $E|X| \geq
> EY$ , thus $EY = 0 \cdot P(|X| < n)+n \cdot P(|X| \geq n) = n \cdot
> P(|X| \geq n) \leq E|X| = P(|X| \geq n) \leq \frac{E|X|}{n}$

And the part I'm having issues with is this here: *Then we have that $0 \leq Y \leq
|X|$ e.g. $P(|X|-Y \geq 0) = 1$*

If we let $P(X=0)=0.5$ and $P(X=1)=0.5$ so $n=0.5$ then we have that $P(Y=0)=0.5$ and $P(Y=0.5) = 0.5$

But can't we also work with probability $P(Y=0.5) \cdot P(X=0)=0.5 \cdot 0.5$ such that $X-Y<0$. Are we allowed to do this or not because $X$ and $Y$ might be dependent from each other?

Comment: Where did you find this proof? Maybe I am missing something but isn't your inequality just a special case of Markov's inequality?

Comment: @charlus It's from a reading and yes the inequality is Markov chain I forgot to write that ^^

Comment: The proof as written is not quite right. It's not enough to have $Y=0$ with probability $P(|X|<n)$ and $Y=n$ with probability $P(|X|\geq n)$. We actually need $Y=0$ *on the event* $\{|X|<n\}$ and $Y=n$ *on the event* $\{|X|\geq n\}$. Then whenever $|X|\geq n$ we have $Y=n$ so $|X|-Y \geq 0$ in this case, and whenever $|X|<n$ we have $Y=0$ so $|X|-Y \geq 0$ in this case as well.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Y=nI(|X|\geq n)$ where $I$ is the indicator function i.e. $I(|X|\geq n)$ equals $1$ when $|X|\geq n$ and is 0 otherwise. The claim is that $|X|\geq Y\geq 0$. It is clear that $Y\geq 0$. To see that $|X|\geq Y$ note that if $|X|\geq n$, then $|X|\geq Y=n$. If $|X|<n$, then $|X|\geq 0=Y$ as desired.